# Sensitivity of placing the picture in multicols environment

Tags: two-column, multicol, paracol

The following piece of code produces different text spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{Picture/}}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}   

\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}[\columnsep 2em]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{picture-sample}
\columnbreak
\begin{exercise}
Compute the integral
\[
\iint_{D}y\,\mathrm{dx}\mathrm{dy},
\]%
where $D$ is represented in the picture to the left.
\end{exercise}
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{2}[\columnsep 2em]
\begin{exercise}
Compute the integral
\[
\iint_{D}y\,\mathrm{dx}\mathrm{dy},
\]%
where $D$ is represented in the picture to the right.
\end{exercise}
\columnbreak
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{picture-sample}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image: The effect of the code]
Why is happening like this? It is clear to me that the picture on the left side is treated differently than the picture on the right side. But why? And how can I fix this issue? Or maybe it is possible to produce the same effect with a different package or another environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not say what the `picture-sample` contains so one can't see what difference you observe, but I presume your picture has more height than the text in the other column. Is that is the case then your example should show in the first multicols a short second column with text and a gap at the bottom and in the second multicols the text spread out in the first column to match the height of the figure in the second column. Is that your problem?

The reason is that multicols is mainly meant for "text" and there is is usually the case that you want the last column to run short if there is not enough text to fill it.

This is controlled by the the counter `finalcolumnbadness` which has a default of `9999`. Your text produces a badness of `10000`(ugly) which why the column is shortened. You can see this when you run your example with the option `balancingshow`, i.e.,

```
\usepackage[balancingshow]{multicol}
```

So one way to make both identical is to add `\setcounter{finalbadness}{10000}`.

But you may prefer no speading out and in that case the solution is

```
\vspace*{\fill}
\columnbreak
```

for which there is an abbreviation `\newcolumn`  --- except that I have implemented it incorrectly -- so it doesn't work and need fixing. The fix is this and will appear in the next release of the package:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\newcolumn{%
   \ifnum\col@number<\tw@
   \PackageError{multicol}%
    {\noexpand\newcolumn outside multicols}%
    {This command can only be used within
     a multicols or multicols* environment.}%
  \else
    \ifvmode
     \nobreak\vfill\kern\z@\penalty -\@Mv\relax  % <--- this was missing the kern
   \else
     \@bsphack
     \vadjust{\nobreak\vfill\kern\z@\penalty -\@Mv\relax}%
     \@esphack
   \fi
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my question with a photo of the pdf output.

Comment: @stefano, then my guess was correct and my answer(s) solves your problem if you use multicols. The fix I mentioned will appear in the next release of multicol.

Comment: @stefano not does it matter, but the example output you show doesn't match the input: both multicols use the same graphic but in your output they magically changed :-)

Answer (score 2):

The package `paracol` does a better job in this case. (It does not try to balance the columns.)

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{Picture/}}
%\usepackage{multicol} % not used
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}   

\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}

\usepackage{paracol} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< added
\setcolumnwidth{0.5\textwidth/2em,0.5\textwidth}%  column separation =2em
\globalcounter{exercise} % counter execise made global

\begin{document}
    
\begin{paracol}{2}
    \noindent\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}% starts in the left column
    \switchcolumn % go to  the right column
    \begin{exercise}
        Compute the integral
        \[
        \iint_{D}y\,\mathrm{dx}\mathrm{dy},
        \]%
        where $D$ is represented in the picture to the left.
    \end{exercise}
    %   \vspace*{50pt}% <<<<<<<<<<< add some separation
    \switchcolumn% go to  the left column
    \begin{exercise}
        Compute the integral
        \[
        \iint_{D}y\,\mathrm{dx}\mathrm{dy},
        \]%
        where $D$ is represented in the picture to the right.
    \end{exercise}
    \switchcolumn% go to  the right columnt
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b} 
\end{paracol}   

\end{document}
```

To add some space between the exercises use

```
\end{exercise}
\vspace*{50pt}% <<<<<<<<<<< add some separation
\switchcolumn% go to  the left column
```

[image: d]